# Reverse constants

Tags: c#, enums, constants

Is there a way to implement a reverse enum or constant file in C#? I have the ID from a List and want to map a constant string to this ID. I was thinking of something like this:

Regular `enum`:

```
public enum StaticUser
{
   DB = 1,
   Order = 2
}
```

What I would need:

```
public enum StaticUser
{
   1 = DB,
   2 = Order
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an enum,

```
public enum StaticUser
{
    DB = 1,
    Order = 2
}
```

If you want to get the name of the member, you could just do `ToString`

```
string staticUserString = ((StaticUser)1).ToString();
```

This casts the literal `1` to `StaticUser` then uses `ToString` to return the string representation of the enum type.

After this example `staticUserString == 'DB'` is `true`.

---

If you want some other constant string for a specific value then you need your own conversion function, somthing like this,

```
public static string ToSpecialString(this StaticUser source)
{
    const string dBString = "Database"

    switch (source)
    {
        case StaticUser.DB:
            return dBString;

        default:
            return source.ToString();
    }
}
```

then you could do

```
string specialStaticUserString = ((StaticUser)1).ToSpecialString();
```

After this example `staticUserString == 'Database'` is `true`.

Comment: Cool, that's it. Didn't know that kind of cast was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast the id to the enum:

```
StaticUser user = (StaticUser)myId;
```